# Primefaces 6 Problem Adding dynamically menuitem with actions

Tags: java, primefaces, menuitem

I've got a problem with menuitem. the goal is to have two menuitems into a menu that pops up  clicking on an icon from a datatable that fires two different actions. everything works fine: teh menu pops up and the menu is rendered.
but when I try to create the menu with  menuItem created server side with two different command defined, I get an error in visualization but, when I use only one command, it works fine.

I tried  to use only one and it works fine, i tried to use first "ONE" and then "TWO" and it works fine but it explodes when i try to use both toghether.

here's the code:

```
DefaultMenuItem firstmenuitem = new DefaultMenuItem("ONE");
firstmenuitem.setIcon("ui-icon-newwin");
firstmenuitem.setCommand("#{myMB.loadDetail1(row, dynMetaCol.id)}");
firstmenuitem.setUpdate("dialog1");
firstmenuitem.setOncomplete("PF('DlgWv1').show()");
menuModel.addElement(firstmenuitem);

DefaultMenuItem secondMenuItem = new DefaultMenuItem("TWO");
secondMenuItem.setIcon("ui-icon-newwin");
secondMenuItem.setCommand("#{myMB.loadDetail2(row, dynMetaCol.id)}");
secondMenuItem.setUpdate("dialog2");
secondMenuItem.setOncomplete("PF('DlgWv2').show()");
menuModel.addElement(secondMenuItem);
```

the xhtml content is this:

```
...

<p:menu overlay="true" trigger="dynaButton" my="left top" at="left bottom" styleClass="ui-menu-context ui-menuitem-link" model="#{myMB.menuModel}"/>

...
```

the result:

```
XML Parsing Error: unclosed CDATA section
Location: http://myaddress/mywebapp/templates/myfolder
/myfolder/mypage.xhtml
Line Number 19, Column 5647:
```

it seems like it is not able to render the actions and the update for the second command.

please help.

Comment: ok, it seems that the problem are these two lines:     secondMenuItem.setUpdate("dialog2");
    secondMenuItem.setOncomplete("PF('DlgWv2').show()");

Comment: ok perhaps I found the problem. this is the one secondMenuItem.setUpdate("dialog2");. I'll try to use the same dialog and put some "if" but I cannot understand how this problem occours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I cannot explain the issue, I found a workarond.

symply, I deleted these lines:

```
firstmenuitem.setUpdate("dialog1");
firstmenuitem.setOncomplete("PF('DlgWv1').show()");

secondMenuItem.setUpdate("dialog2");
secondMenuItem.setOncomplete("PF('DlgWv2').show()");
```

and into each action method (loadDetail1 and loadDetail2) I use this simple method:

```
public static void updateAndShowDialog(String dialogId, String widgetVarName) {
    RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    requestContext.update(dialog);
    requestContext.execute("PF('" + widgetVarName + "').show()");
}
```

hope this can help.

best regards.